# Context.Site is null within LinkProvider code triggered from FileSystemWatcher callback

Tags: sitecore-api, pipelines

Scenario in our Sitecore 8.1 instance is that, we have a .NET `FileSystemWatcher` object that is initialized in `Application_BeginRequest` of `global.asax`. When a file is dropped in the watched folder, callback code interacts with Sitecore and at some point, attempts to add a new item version (via `Item.Versions.AddVersion`). At this point, a `NullReferenceException` is raised and we've traced this to a custom `LinkProvider` code that uses `Context.Site`, that turned out to be the null reference.

Is this expected behavior? Any suggestions, how we can work around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

#### This is expected behaviour.

The reason you do not have a `Context.Site` (or any context for that matter) is, that you are not in a Sitecore page execution context.

The very short explanation is; Sitecore will build up the `Context` as part of the `httpRequestBegin` pipeline which is only fired - which makes sense I hope - when a HttpRequest begins.

In your case, your code is triggered by .NET in form of a `FileSystemWatcher` event. Not a page request. Under these circumstances, your code cannot rely on any page execution context, and must be able to execute without it.

The LinkProvider in question should fail gracefully without a context site.

Answer (score 0):

As you overwrote the `Global.asax` this could be the reason, because Sitecore has its own. So maybe you call your custom implementation before Sitecore calls its own pipelines. To fix this try to use the `httpRequestBegin` pipeline.
Here is the exact mapping between `Global.asax` methods and Sitecore pipelines ([source](https://laubplusco.net/global-asax-sitecore-pipelines/)):

> 1. Application_Start: initialize
> 2. Application_BeginRequest: preprocessRequest / httpRequestBegin
> 3. Application_EndRequest: httpRequestEnd
> 4. Session_End: sessionEnd
> 5. Application_End: shutdown

Not recommended to overwrite `Global.asax` which is provided by Sitecore.